# Reuse already instanciated objects parsed by Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am using the gson library to parse a json object that has the following structure:

```
{
    "data" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "type" : "student",
            "name" : "Student 1",
            "subjects" : [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "type" : "subject"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "type" : "student",
            "name" : "Student 2",
            "subjects" : [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "type" : "subject",
                    "name" : "Math"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "type" : "office",
            "name" : "student 3",
            "subjects" : [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "type" : "subject",
                    "name" : "History"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "type" : "subject",
                    "name" : "History"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is a very basic example, there are 3 students who assist to 0 or many classes. As you can see 2 or more students can have the same reference to a specific subject, but when I parse the object, Student 1 will have an object for subject 1, Student 2 will have a different object but with same information as the one for Student 1, so my question basically is, is there a way to reuse the already created objects? In this case is not a problem to have multiple references, but say you have a lot more objects, this will turn into a memory problem.

In theory what comes to mind is that before creating an object instance, there should be some kind of pool, so I look using the id and type, if I find the object I return it, otherwise I let the parser to create the instance for me. There is the JsonDeserializer interface, but there is a known problem for using the JSON deserialization context, also I cannot just do a new Gson() inside of it because my main Gson has some deserializers and strategies that I want to reuse. I could just recreate the gson but I don't think that's ideal, there should be a better way of doing it.

Also, I already have a TypeAdapter that initially preprocess the JSON that comes from the server, basically it removes some attributes and add some others resulting in the example, but I could not make it check for each individual object like the JsonDeserializer would do

I will appreciate any help or thoughts on this.

Comment: Your subjects share the same ids for different classes. Is it a typo in your example data? + Is `office` a typo too?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv sorry yes it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do is by *flattening the structure.* i.e. you can skip sending entire subject objects in student object.

**For example, a student object:**

```
"student": [
    {
        id: "1234567890",
        name: "Bhalchandra Wadekar",
        subject: [
            "CS4040",
            "CS4010"
        ]
    }
]
```

where, CS4040 and CS4010 are identifiers of individual subjects.

**The subject objects:**

```
"subject": [
    {
        id: "CS4040",
        name: "Mobile Design and Development"
    },
    {
        id: "CS4010",
        name: "Major Project"
    }
]
```

The benefits of using this method are:

1. Reducing the amount of data you are receiving on individual request leading to **faster response time.**
2. **A single object in memory for each subject.** Therefore, you will be creating and using one object no matter how many students assist that subject.

Comment: This is actually what the server returns, but basically I would need to add a function to search for each type when I need them which will add more complexity to the code, every time I pass on an array of references I would need to add code to look for the real object

Comment: A map can solve the issue of looking for subjects for a given identifier. :)